# how to remove trailing slash on post request nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, configuration, trailing-slash

I'm trying to remove trailing slash on http post method, when i try to re-write the URL using `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;` it doesn't work for me

The upstream should receive in this format  `/x/y` if the Http POST is coming in these format

- **location /x/y/ ==> location /x/y**
- **location /x/y ==> location /x/y**

This is the nginx configuration

```
  upstream backend {
            server 127.0.0.1:8778;
            # Number of idle keepalive connections per worker process.
            keepalive 35;
    }


    location /x/y  {        
                    limit_except POST {
                            deny all;
                    }
                    proxy_pass  http://backend;
                    proxy_buffering on;
                    include proxy.conf;
            }
```

The problem here is when the upstream see the URI is in this format `/x/y/` it rejected the request, what should be the correct rewrite rule for this so that if the http post comes in the format like `/x/y` or `/x/y/` the upstream should always see `/x/y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `permanent` will cause the `rewrite` to generate a redirect with a 301 response. What you need is an internal adjustment of the URI before sending it upstream:

```
location /x/y {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 break;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.